# Ruby where refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm refactoring a method and I'm having trouble in refactoring the following code to a simple `.where`

```rb
def check_hp_repayments
  include = [:finance_detail]
  @finances = Finance.legacy_find(:all,
      :include => include,
      :conditions => ["finance_details.next_repayment_date < ? and finance_details.loan_term > 0", Time.now]
    )
end
```

`legacy_find` is a piece of custom code we have in the app, why I don't know so I'm trying to replace these with actual `.where`'s and `.find`'s

EDIT:

Here is the `legacy_find` method

```rb
def self.legacy_find(type, args=nil)
  # need to add capability to handle array of id's
  if type.kind_in?([Numeric, String, Array]) && !args
    result =  self.find(type)
  elsif !args
    result =  self.send(type.to_s)
  else
    result = self

    if type.kind_of?(Array)
      if !args[:conditions]
         args[:conditions] = ["1 = 1"]
      elsif args[:conditions].kind_of?(String)
        args[:conditions] = [args[:conditions]]
      end

      args[:conditions][0] = '(' + args[:conditions][0] + ')'

      args[:conditions][0] += " AND `" + self.table_name + "`.`id` in(" + type.join(',') + ")"
    elsif type && !type.kind_of?(Symbol)
      if !args[:conditions]
         args[:conditions] = ["1 = 1"]
      elsif args[:conditions].kind_of?(String)
        args[:conditions] = [args[:conditions]]
      end

      args[:conditions][0] = '(' + args[:conditions][0] + ')'

      args[:conditions][0] += " AND `" + self.table_name + "`.`id` = ?"
      args[:conditions].push(type)
    end

    result      = self.legacy_conditions(args)

    if type && ((type.kind_of?(String) && type.to_i.to_s == type) || type.kind_of?(Numeric))
      result = result.first
    elsif type && !type.kind_of?(Symbol)
      result = result.to_a
    else
      result =  type ? result.send((type == :all ? 'to_a' : type).to_s) : result
    end
  end

  new_result = result
  return new_result
end
```

Here is the `legacy_conditions`

```rb
def self.legacy_conditions(args)
          return self if !args

            args[:conditions] = [] if args[:conditions] && args[:conditions][0].kind_of?(String) && args[:conditions][0].size == 0

            result = self
            result = result.where(args[:conditions]) if (args.has_key?(:conditions) && args[:conditions] && args[:conditions].size > 0)
            result = result.select(args[:select]) if args.has_key?(:select) && args[:select]
            result = result.includes(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
            result = result.includes(args[:include_without_references]) if args.has_key?(:include_without_references) && args[:include_without_references]
            result = result.references(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
            result = result.joins(args[:joins]) if args.has_key?(:joins) && args[:joins]
            result = result.order(args[:order]) if args.has_key?(:order) && args[:order]
            result = result.group(args[:group]) if args.has_key?(:group) && args[:group]
            result = result.limit(args[:limit]) if args.has_key?(:limit) && args[:limit]
            result = result.offset(args[:offset]) if args.has_key?(:offset) && args[:offset]
            result = result.from(args[:from]) if args.has_key?(:from) && args[:from]
            result = result.lock(args[:lock]) if args.has_key?(:lock) && args[:lock]
            result = result.readonly(args[:readonly]) if args.has_key?(:readonly) && args[:readonly]
            result
        end

        def human_attribute_name(attr, opts = {})
          self.class.human_attribute_name(attr, opts)
        end
    end
end
```

Rails version: 6.1.3.2

Comment: Can you add the definition of that `legacy_find` method? And tell what version of Rails you're using?

Comment: That method doesn't seem to be handling the `includes` option it receives, maybe is in `legacy_conditions`. Anyway, you can try looking at what SQL that call generates, and if  its Rails `where` counterpart matches with that, you can just deprecate `legacy_find`.

Comment: I can imagine is just something like this `Finance.includes(:finance_detail).where("finance_details.next_repayment_date < ? and finance_details.loan_term > 0", Time.now)`

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've added the `legacy_conditions` method

Comment: Yes, I see. As I said, just create your query, add some tests and check if it returns the same as using the legacy find. If that's ok, you're ready to start deprecating that.

Comment: @SebastianPalma the issue with that though is that the page is erroring out so there's no way to see the current query, this is what I'm getting https://i.gyazo.com/af7abb1133a9cf21eb8cc573d1394f33.png

Comment: But that somehow is failing somewhere else, because in that context there's no mention of FinanceDetail. You don't need to test it through the browser, you can open the Rails console and run your query there.

Comment: @debugabug Read the error message; it says there is no constant `Finance`. Where is that class defined? Does it definitely exist? Maybe it's not being eager-loaded, because it's located in a non-standard location?

Comment: The class `Finance` is inside a base `Account` model so not sure whether it's worth extracting this into it's own model https://i.gyazo.com/30d195e0af1adf9b683ad2786d7813d8.png

Comment: @SebastianPalma So looking into the account model, there are 26+ different classes which is crazy so it looks like a lot of stuff has just been stuffed into there. Here's the full screenshot https://i.gyazo.com/0f90eae0043d3acb496e3abe45f9d653.png

Comment: Try `Account::Finance.where(...)`

Comment: There is a `FinanceDetail` model in the models folder yes

Comment: Yeah, forget about FinanceDetail, it was my bad, I got confused by the error message.

Comment: Ah OK, yeah so if I try something like this `Account::Finance.where("finance_details.next_repayment_date < ? and finance_details.loan_term > 0", Time.now)` I get `uninitialized constant Account::Finance`

Comment: Try moving that Finance class outside that file, to its own (app/models/finance.rb) and then doing `Finance.where(...)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's moved onto another error so my assumption now is that it's running. Thanks.